# I can't access my samba shares. Ubuntu Server 20.04

Tags: server, samba, 20.04, do-release-upgrade

Ubuntu Server 20.04

[image: Unable to access locatin]

After I upgraded (do-release-upgrade) to Server 20.04. I can't access my samba shares. when I double click on my server I get this. Please help

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. As the answer below solved your problem please accept the answer as correct by clicking on the grey check mark ✔️ and turning it into the green check mark ✅ next to the answer. It will help others.

Answer (score 6):

Just so I understand the question: You are trying to access Ubuntu Server 20.04 from another Linux client? If that is so it won't work by default.

You have three choices:

**[1] Enable SMB1 on the server:**

Edit /etc/samba/smb.conf and under the workgroup = WORKGROUP line add this one - NT1 is samba speak for SMB1:

```
server min protocol = NT1
```

Then restart smbd:

```
sudo service smbd restart
```

**[2] Keep smb.conf as it is but have the client ask for the server and share explicitly either through Connect to Server or in the Location bar as**

`smb://server-name.local/share-name`

The .local part requires you add the avahi-daemon package to your server. You can try it without the .local and just use the host name but that can be problematic. Or you can use the server's IP address.

**[3] Use a CIFS mount from the client. For example:**

```
sudo mount -t cifs //server-name.local/share-name /mountpoint -o guest,uid=1000
```

After some syntax changes you can set this up as a systemd automount in fstab so the user doesn't have to use the terminal.

Comment: Problem solved thangs. I used (server min protocol = NT1) and everything is running now

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I also had to use `server min protocol = NT1` for the various media devices around my house to be able to browse the server again after an upgrade (in addition to `smb://` URLs in Nemo.)

Comment: By removing local solved my problem (2023 here!) I could not connect two ubuntu computers, its shares!!!! Thanks. Why this worked? What ".local" does?

Answer (score 2):

Exactly as [Morbius1](https://askubuntu.com/a/1236584/348964) said. Add either (or both) lines to your `smb.conf`:

```
client min protocol = NT1
server min protocol = NT1
```

Answer (score 0):

The list of arguments to access the samba shares has likely changed after the upgrade. Take a look at [this page](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-configure-samba-server-share-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux) to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error on Ubuntu 20.04 and this was the way to solve it:

#### Remove all samba related files and configuration files

```
sudo apt purge python3-samba samba-common samba-common-bin samba-dsdb-modules samba samba-vfs-modules smbclient
```

Optionally you can remove the packages and maintain the configuration files, but this could left wrong files in the middle. It's better to do a backup of your configuration files. Anyway, if you want to try it, use `remove` instead of `purge`.

#### Reboot

Not sure if it's completely necessary, but I do it this way.

#### Share files

Open Nautilus and share a file or directory. A warning is showed indicating the sharing service is not installed and allowing you to click to install it. Click, install and you're done!

The nautilus-share package creates the `/var/lib/samba/usershares/` directory with the right permissions and added your user to `sambashare` group, and it's ready to be used by other users too.

Answer (score 0):

For others still searching for an answer to this issue:
I had this issue after fresh install of 20.04, even my old smb.conf from 18.04 which had worked, would not allow windows(10) to see the samba shares. While adding `server min protocol = NT1` to smb.conf and/or enabling SMBv1 on windows has worked for some it did not solve the issue for me.

The only solution that worked for me was fairly simple, it was to install WSDD to enable Windows web services discovery, guide and explanation here: [WSDD set up guide](https://devanswers.co/discover-ubuntu-machines-samba-shares-windows-10-network/).
It worked for me out of the box with the standard smb.conf after disabling firewall.
`sudo ufw disable`

If you feel you really need firewall enabled (ie not already behind router firewall) there is a guide to setting firewall for WSDD [here](https://fitzcarraldoblog.wordpress.com/2020/06/16/using-ws-discovery-to-enable-windows-10-to-browse-smb-shares-in-my-home-network-of-linux-computers/) at step 11.

I also suggest and easy test to see if your samba shares are actually available on the network is to check with a file manager app the supports network locations from an android phone. If the they are available to android but not windows, it would indicate that samba is working correctly but there is a window compatibly issue that the above solution should resolve.

Answer (score 0):

I had a fresh install of 20.04, and it took me these two steps to get the sharing working with Ubuntu 18:

Configure the workgroup's protocol at /etc/samba/smb.conf (here SMB3 wouldn't work):

```
client min protocol = CORE
server min protocol = CORE
```

Set a Samba password for the user:

```
sudo smbpasswd -a <user name>
```

Answer (score 0):

Samba stopped working from Windows for me after we disabled SMBv1.  This was fixed by updating `smb.conf` to switch:

```
map to guest = bad user
```

to

```
map to guest = never
```