# Ubuntu Studio Shared Folder Question

Tags: networking, server, permissions, mount, samba

I've been using Ubuntu and Ubuntu derivatives for quite some time now.

Probably once a year or so, I prefer to do a clean install and "start everything over". I have a set of scripts/lists/instructions so that I can put my computer back to my preferred configuration in a short period of time.

One of those is setting up a shared folder. I've had a "never fail" method for doing this, but now with the update to Studio 20.04, it will not work. I've been reading a number of websites, but it seems that all of the Samba information is old or just doesn't work correctly any more.

Here is the old method that I used to share a folder on my network:

```
sudo adduser nobody users
sudo adduser 81firearms users
sudo mkdir -p /srv/samba/laptop
sudo chown root:users /srv/samba/laptop
sudo chmod 2775 /srv/samba/laptop
```

Logout and log back in.

Add to smb.conf file.

```
[laptop]
        comment = laptop
        path = /srv/samba/laptop
        browseable = yes
        guest ok = yes
        force group = users
        writeable = yes
        create mask = 0664
        force directory mode = 0775
```

Then, type:

```
sudo service smbd restart
```

I finished installing Ubuntu Studio today and followed this routine once again.

I went to another computer (a Puppy Linux PC) to check, and it sees the share, but when I try to open it, I get this message:

> Mount: UBUNTU-STUDIO laptop failed. The server may be refusing you
>   access to this share or your password may be incorrect.

Now, what am I doing wrong? Normally, when I follow this procedure, I end up with a folder on my laptop that I can access, read, and write from any folder, without having to put in any password.

Can anyone spot what the error is, or does someone have a "fool proof" method for setting up a shared folder?

Why in 2020 is there not a "works every time" GUI for Ubuntu/Debian derivatives?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1236510/i-cant-access-my-samba-shares-ubuntu-server-20-04

Comment: Thanks for the link. This fixed it: 

I edited /etc/samba/smb.conf and under the workgroup = WORKGROUP line I added this:

server min protocol = NT1
Then restart smbd:

sudo service smbd restart

Comment: Based on your comment this question is a duplicate of [I can't access my samba shares. Ubuntu Server 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1236510/i-cant-access-my-samba-shares-ubuntu-server-20-04). I am voting to close this question.